# Joint thickness for glass block spacers

Tags: brick, mortar, glass

I am getting these glass block spacers for 4" blocks but the website I got it from says nothing about the thickness of the joint it provides.

[image]

I would like to build my framing before it arrives (could be up to 2 weeks) in the meantime but, for that, I need to factor the joint to calculate the width my glass block window. Can you guess it from the picure (my guess is something like 3/16-1/4")?

Answer (score 2):

This site says 4” modules in both directions. (I know some glass blocks come in 6” modules.)

https://m.lowes.com/pd/SEVES-24-Pack-2-375-in-x-4-in-Non-directional-Glass-Block-Spacer/1000117677

So to answer your question, the mortar joint is going to be as wide as necessary to provide a 4” module. (The spacer will make the joint the correct width.)

Don’t forget to add one mortar joint width for your wood frame

Comment: To clarify, the answer is 4" minus the actual dimension of your particular blocks. The thickness of the spacer arms is not related to the final mortar joint thickness.